# Is it always the case that the nameof() is equal to the typeof().Name?

Tags: c#, reflection

I've tested Class, Methods, Fields, Properties, and Enums to see if there are any cases when this is not true?

[DotNetFiddle Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JpBmHr)

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var fooType = typeof(Foo);
        ThrowIfNotEqual(fooType.Name, nameof(Foo));

        var fi = fooType.GetField(nameof(Foo.field));
        ThrowIfNotEqual(fi.Name, nameof(Foo.field));

        var pi = fooType.GetProperty(nameof(Foo.property));
        ThrowIfNotEqual(pi.Name, nameof(Foo.property));

        var mi = fooType.GetMethod(nameof(Foo.method));
        ThrowIfNotEqual(mi.Name, nameof(Foo.method));

        var fi2 = fooType.GetNestedTypes()[0];
        ThrowIfNotEqual(fi2.Name, nameof(Foo.myEnum));

        ThrowIfNotEqual("TestThisMethod", "WorksAsExpected");
    }

    public static void ThrowIfNotEqual(string a, string b)
    {
        if (a != b) throw new InvalidOperationException($"Are Not Equal: {a} != {b}");
    }

    public class Foo
    {
        public string field;
        public string property { get; set; }
        public void method() { }
        public enum myEnum
        {
            A
        }
    }
}
```

Results:

> Run-time exception (line -1): Are Not Equal: TestThisMethod != WorksAsExpected

Comment: Isn't it supposed to throw the exception as per `ThrowIfNotEqual("TestThisMethod", "WorksAsExpected");` code? What's the issue you are facing here.... if you are not getting exception from any other call of `ThrowIfNotEqual` method, that means `a` and `b` for those calls are the same..

Comment: If you remove `ThrowIfNotEqual("TestThisMethod", "WorksAsExpected");` line for code, there is not exception being thrown... the code works just fine without that line of code.

Comment: `public class Foo<T>` would break it

Comment: I find that `nameof()` is mostly used to get a variable name or method name, so that you don't have to worry about hard-coded strings in exception messages when refactoring names.

Comment: It was suppose to throw so I knew it was working if two strings weren't equal.  Negative test case, I just left it in.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is it always the case that the `nameof()` is equal to the
>   `typeof().Name`?

No there are lots ways to break this, just as an example

```
public class Foo<T>
```

**E.g**

```
var fooType = typeof(Foo<string>);
Console.WriteLine(fooType.Name);
Console.WriteLine(nameof(Foo<string>));
```

**Output**

```
Foo`1
Foo
```

There are also many situations where you will get compiler errors on just predefined types using `nameof()`

```
Console.WriteLine(nameof(int)); //CS1525    Invalid expression term 'int'
```

---

[nameof (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/nameof#remarks)

**Remarks**

> Because the argument needs to be an expression syntactically, there
>   are many things disallowed that are not useful to list. The following
>   are worth mentioning that produce errors